# A simple way to cover all concatenation combinations

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating a search function for my project utilizing the LIKE `mysqli` query.

In my attempt to make the functionality as 'user-friendly' as possibly I am finding myself including a lot of CONCAT request.

I.e.

```
$contact = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE k_name LIKE '%$searching%' OR f_name LIKE '%$searching%' OR l_name LIKE '%$searching%' OR concat( f_name,l_name ) LIKE '%$searching%' OR concat( k_name, l_name ) LIKE '%$searching%' OR mobile LIKE '%$searching%' OR phone LIKE '%$searching%' OR w_phone LIKE '%$searching%' OR w_fax LIKE '%$searching%' OR k_email LIKE '%$searching%' OR email LIKE '%$searching%' OR w_email LIKE '%$searching%' order by id LIMIT 5");
```

The idea here is to allow the user to type in their search in any order to find exactly what they are looking for.

For example user 'A' might not remember the name of the street so they search the street number and suburb. Or they might remember a contacts first name and suburb but not the last name.

So my question is, is there a simple entry that would cover all possible concatenation combinations of the individual WHERE selects?

Example

```
$contact = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE concat(all) LIKE '%$searching%' OR f_name LIKE '%$searching%' OR l_name LIKE '%$searching%'OR mobile LIKE '%$searching%' OR phone LIKE '%$searching%' OR w_phone LIKE '%$searching%' OR w_fax LIKE '%$searching%' OR k_email LIKE '%$searching%' OR email LIKE '%$searching%' OR w_email LIKE '%$searching%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the result I was chasing I followed the advise of @RavinderReddy.

I started off by exploding the string

```
$search_text = $_GET['userInput'];  
$searching = strtolower($search_text);
$explode = explode(" ", $searching);
```

I then checked the individual explodes of contents and output the result

```
if($explode[0] != ''){
    $firstterm = $explode[0];
}else{
    $firstterm = '@@@';
}
if($explode[1] != ''){
    $secondterm = $explode[1];
}else{
    $secondterm = '@@@';
}
if($explode[2] != ''){
    $thirdterm = $explode[2];
}else{
    $thirdterm = '@@@';
}
}
```

I used the '@@@' because it will never match any of my data.

Finally I modified my mysqli query to reflect and include the new OR LIKE search terms.

```
$contact = $mysqli->query("
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE 
f_name LIKE '%$firstterm%'
OR l_name LIKE '%$firstterm%'
OR concat( f_name,l_name ) LIKE '%$firstterm%'

OR f_name LIKE '%$secondterm%'
OR l_name LIKE '%$secondterm%'
OR concat( f_name,l_name ) LIKE '%$secondterm%'

order by id LIMIT 5");
```

Something to consider is I have set up my database so that all entries do not include any spaces in them. I have done so for the purposes of consistence when displaying my data and giving the user the ability to 'format' their search in anyway they desire and still find their intended result.

The next step I am looking to take is to try and find a way to 'ORDER' by the most amount of matching characters as apposed to 'id'. The reason being if I type 'C Blogs' looking for 'Craig Blogs' the 'C' will register a hit on everyone of my contacts because of the email address '.Com'.

So if I can get it to ORDER by most amount of matching characters the top result should theoretically be 'Craig Blogs'.

Note: I am new to this site and new to answering my question. I am sorry if the formatting is poor or if I have over-explained things.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Concat_ws` :-

```
WHERE concat_ws(' ',k_name,f_name,l_name,phone...) LIKE '%$searching%'
```

Comment: In this case if I type a f_name then l_name then phone it works. But if I type f_name then k_name or anything else out of order it doesn't work. I am looking for a solution that would cover all combinations.

Comment: ***@Bjaeg***: No. If you want to use a *single* search string to compare on all fields then it MUST have *ANY ONE OF* `f_name` or `l_name` or `phone` or `etc_fld` values. If you input both ( `phone` and `f_name` ) or ( `email` and `l_name` ) kind of random combinations as part of your single search string, it is not going to work. If you want such behaviour, then you have to split search string into multiples and use *them* in the query with that many or more number of `like` combinations. Otherwise, `Rahautos` solution should be working.

Comment: @RavinderReddy Thank you for explaining that in further detail.